# How to find ip address of email sender of yahoo mail or gmail?

Tags: email

How to find ip address of email sender of yahoo mail or gmail?

Comment: Where's the rest of your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a thought - If you are looking for the IP in order to track down a spammer or something similar - better report the email address directly to yahoo or gmail.

One more issue is that if the IP used to send the mail is/was dynamic, it can possibly help you only aproximately geo-locate the sender, nothing more.

Answer (score 6):

There is a technique that sometimes works, and it's a well-known trick used by spammers.

Reply to the email with an HTML email that includes an image hosted by a server you control, with a unique query string in the URL. If the person opens the email AND displays images, your image will load. You can see which IP address loaded the image, and match that with the email address where you sent the image. Of course, even if this works it will give you the IP address where they read your message, not the one from which they sent the first email. This trick is the main reason that email programs check before they load images now.

You could also sue them, get a subpeona and force Google or Yahoo to get the IP address from their logs.

Comment: Very nice idea. I might try this

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the mail headers, you can see who sent it and the host IP, but sender IP addresses aren't included in the header.

Comment: Actually, they are with most providers, but I think with Yahoo, not anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into the mail header which is where you can find the ip address.

Edit:  Funny that this was the correct answer but was the only one that got a negative vote.  You can go to this link to find out more http://aruljohn.com/info/howtofindipaddress/#gmail and to use some scripts that will make it easier for you.  But in short, the IP address can usually be found in the header.  Reading the header is different for every email provider so you will have to read to find out how.  Some email services such as Google will never share the sender IP.  But I've heard that if a sender uses a mail client such as Thunderbird, that the IP can always be tracked, haven't tested it yet though.  Good luck!

Comment: Incorrect. Mail agents almost never add a "user IP" header to outgoing mail. Your comment above has nothing to to with email headers.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy to track the IP address.
And to track address of sender first we need to retrieve IP address is the sender from the mail and then convert that IP address in location with help of no of websites which offer this feature.
It's a different process for both Yahoo and gmail and putting whole steps will take around 70 lines so I an just putting it's link I found on a website
 http://www.rybersoft.com/2016/04/how-to-find-location-of-email-sender.html